# How to get sizes of files in directory?

Tags: c#

I want to to list all files sizes in some directory. In java I would use the following code:

```
for (File file: Paths.get(directory).toFile().listFiles()) {
    System.out.println(file.length());
}
```

How can I achieve the same in C#?

Comment: This should not be that difficoult to find online - have you googled something like "c# list files in directory"? PS instead of "file weight" try searching for "file size".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this demo code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        var files = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(path);

        Console.WriteLine($"{"Filename",-18} {"Size (bytes)"}");
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var info = new System.IO.FileInfo(file);
            Console.WriteLine($"{info.Name,-18} {info.Length}");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: scr1]